# Dealing with bathroom/water/other breaks during audio conference

Tags: professionalism

**Summary:** We all have need to attend *mandatory* breaks, e.g. bathroom break, choked on a candy, or cat started shredding the couch. How to announce/manifest it professionally while on an audio-only conference call?

---

In an office situation, one would normally *quietly* leave the room (with or without an explicit gesture "I'll be right back") and *quietly* take the seat again. Office situation vary. I imagine a meeting of 3 to 10 people, with or without external participants (e.g. customers, suppliers), where everyone potentially have to speak. Not a public conference situation with one speaker. With or without a *presentation*.

I have been searching for the correct etiquette, but I only found tips for **video** conferences, where one would normally turn mic&camera off so that the others would understand one is off for a while. (or leave the room, mic off, to let the others see the empty seat)

But in my environment we normally have audio-only conferences, internally and with the customers.

And with the exception of the situation where the person **is** the main speaker (the break is either postponed or for all), what should be the appropriate etiquette to leave a meeting for a short interruption while making the other participants *aware* of own absence?

This assumes the person is not just an attendant, but might receive questions at some point. A situation such as "Alex, do you believe what Bob just said is technically feasible?" and Alex not responding is a bit embarassing.

I have been thinking of:

- **Warning the others**

  Unmutin and saying "sorry, I must go and be back in a short while" interrupts the focus to the speaker
- **Silently leave**

  As I said, it might create a moment of embarassment when you are required to answer and other are not aware that you are temporarily out
- **Disconnect**

  Has a side effect of distraction. I have experienced this multiple times. When one disappears from the meeting, others normally think of a connection problems and start commenting "Alex is offline. They may have network problems", and sometimes pause the meeting. Reappearing in a meeting may cause another distraction by the beep of the medium. Sometimes people stop until the person reappears. Excusing self "sorry I had to go to bathroom" is a bit awful when the others waited for you.

  Sneaking into a conference room, conversely, does not create much distraction as someone will look at you, indeed, but the presentation/speech continues.
- **Bring the device to the bathroom (MUTED!!!!)**

  Works best for bathroom breaks and only if device (e.g. laptop) can be carried. One could even decide to shortly unmute when inquired.
  May not work for breaks such as a postman ringing the bell.

Comment: What are the capabilities of the audio conferencing software/hardware? Is there a chat you can use to let everyone know you'll be back soon without interrupting the speaker?

Comment: i've added summary and added more examples of "mandatory" breaks. Feel free to edit/roll back

Comment: If you are the speaker, you plan ahead, you shouldn’t be choking on anything as the speaker.  If you are in the audience, keep yourself muted, only the host typically can see you anyways.  The host can see if your “available”, it really seems, you are overthinking the situation

Comment: Bathroom (or any behavior you'd be embarassed of) on mute is risky--compare the pro: you dont miss what anyone says for a minute, against the potential con: you forget to mute and everyone hears you pee--I always opt to miss a minute of the meeting because the risk isn't worth it

Comment: One need not explain WHY you are stepping out. Either on chat if that's an option just type/say "Excuse me, be back in a minute" or "I need to step away for a moment". Then announce your return at the next pause in conversation if necessary or if you know they'll be expecting your input. Just because phones are portable does not mean you must treat them as always with you; "leave it at your virtual desk". I mistakenly took my phone to the washroom once to grab a paper towel, just to have the jet hand dryer blast over the phone to all.  Howling noise!

Comment: As a side note, the others should also be realistic and not be offended any time someone leaves for a short while. Everybody needs to relax a bit an realise we re not computers but humans.

Comment: @chiliNUT I use bluetooth headphones without a mic, and a wired mic on my desk, with the desktop Zoom client.  That means I can listen in without the risk of accidentally unmuting myself

Comment: Personally if I start truly choking on something when on a Zoom call, decorum is out; my focus is 100% on survival! I'm guessing you mean like a coughing fit? In that case I'd just mute myself, possibly apologizing if I can, and if the others on the call heard the coughing it would make sense and be just fine. But if I was really choking, I'd work on not dying without worrying about professionalism.

Comment: I (and all my coworkers) usually type "brb" or something equivalent.

Comment: Never ever ever take your device into the toilet with you. If you forget or fat-finger the button, you'll never live it down.

Comment: if you feel like taking the device with you into the bathroom from time to time or anywhere else outside of your typical home-office room/location  at the least make sure to have a hard block for your camera in place. you can explain most noises away with a white lie in case of an "accident" (had to wash my hands because I spilled my drink or the like)... video, not so much.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Mute your microphone and type a comment into the chat instead explaining what you are doing. It is a quiet way of excusing yourself from the meeting without disrupting the speaker.

Comment: "I'll be right back."
"Back"

Comment: "afk" "re" for the elder

Comment: Though this does assume whatever they're using has a chat channel. People using good ol' phone to call in don't have that.

Comment: @mxyzplk well it's seems reasonable to assume not everybody is using a simple phone... if any question is let without answer, anybody with access to chat can tell "ho I see xxx said he will be right back soon"...

Comment: Another option is to privately message someone else on the call who can let everyone know you've gone away for a moment should you happen to be called on. When you get back they should let you know if you were indeed called on, which gives you a chance to announce you're back.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Privately messaging someone may work, but it can also be quite unreliable, as not everyone checks/sees their messages all the time, especially not when on a call.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, I would glance at my messages in an attempt to find out why the missing person is missing (and so I know whether or not to start with the "You're on mute" chant).

Comment: @mxyzplk that's a good excuse to have others read the chat every now and then. i noticed that nobody in my meetings ever read google meet, while everyone will do in teams

Comment: Don't forget to type another comment once you are back

Comment: @mxyzplk some systems allow dial-in for voice while logged in on a PC for chat and to watch the presenter

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Dude I'm only in my twenties and I relate to that...

Comment: I think this answer only applies to bigger meetings (or presentations) where your constant participation is not very important. If it’s a small meeting or discussion it’s better to interrupt and ask for a short break.

Comment: In my experience "brb" ([I'll] be right back) and "back" are conventional. Of course whatever is sufficiently clear is fine.

Answer (score 21):

You've had a couple of solutions to your direct problem.

How about solving the underlying problem? Why don't these meetings have pre-scheduled bathroom breaks? Five minutes every hour seems like the common, professional thing to arrange for. It sounds like a recurring problem in your organisation too. Encourage others to include this nicety for better meeting flow the other 55 minutes.

The general problem is that if someone feels the need to temporarily slip out of a meeting, they have been bound to the meeting for too long -- either because the meeting is going on for too long without a break, or because they shouldn't even have been in all of that meeting to begin with.

Comment: This only adresses bathroom breaks and assumes you can go to the bathroom on demand. Plus, I sometimes spend my days jumping from one call to another, frequently with no time in between. And nobody accounts for a break in a 1h meeting...

Comment: Breaks between meetings are nice, however, in many jobs there certainly are routine situations where people may have meetings that not only don't have a break but even overlap (e.g. multiple consecutive meetings where a previous meeting might overrun its planned time a bit). Often, the beginning and the end of such consecutive meetings are key parts which should not be missed and it would be better to make any breaks needed (for whatever reason, presumably valid) at an opportune moment in the middle of a meeting.

Comment: That still sounds to me like either a broken meeting culture, or a mismanaged personal schedule -- or most likely, both. I would still strongly reflect over how much actual useful, value-added work really gets done in these meetings, and think of ways to improve meeting efficiency to the point where I have five minutes every hour for bathroom breaks, making notes, attending other urgent matters, etc.

Comment: Most human adults can go to the bathroom on demand, when given regular opportunity to. And it's also not that I think urgent matters will pop up regularly every 60 minutes either, it's that they can usually wait 55 minutes for your attendance as long as you know ahead of time that that is the most they'll have to wait.

Comment: That's all very nice, but does assume a certain level of influence over the corporate culture.  In most WFH situations (@LaurentS.) you should be able to schedule almost all other breaks.  The doorbell is the obvious other case, but that's usually very brief

Comment: I agree the doorbell is a bit of an odd one out. I would probably not answer it if I was in a meeting -- after all, I wouldn't have had I been in the office anyway. Maybe if I was expecting something important, but then I would announce that early in the meeting. That should also not be a recurring problem...

Comment: This is not really about influence over corporate culture. It's about being nice to the meeting host. "Hey, do you want a quick tip that could improve attendance and meeting flow?" Or, in the case of back-to-back meetings, "I'd love to come but I have another matter to attend to at that hour. It shouldn't take more than 10 minutes. Can we start the meeting 10 past?" If you're truly needed at the meeting they can't do much but oblige. (But the best thing is if you block off time in your calendar after meetings so it's clear to everyone you're not immediately available.)

Comment: *I agree the doorbell is a bit of an odd one out. I would probably not answer it if I was in a meeting -- after all, I wouldn't have had I been in the office anyway.* The key difference is that if you are in an office, either there will be someone *not* in the meeting who can handle the deliveries, etc. or if it is an "everyone" meeting, someone will be designated to deal with deliveries, etc. When everyone is in their own home, some people will inevitably be by themselves and have no reasonable choice except to answer the doorbell.

Comment: More importantly, if your company expects you to work from home they must also expect that _you are in your home and not an office_.  It is not the same environment and the same expectations cannot apply.  It is not inappropriate to jump out of a meeting for one minute to receive a package, etc., and if your company feels that it is then perhaps it is time to find a better employer or at least demand that they fully finance your home office.

Comment: I think that the real problem is too many meetings and meetings are too long - not that meetings lack scheduled breaks.  I have young kids and without much notice I will have to break up an inter-kid fight or something else crazy.  They don't conform to the corporate schedule.  "BRB" works just fine.

Comment: @MatthewRead: If I expect a delivery (and the prediction for that is quite good nowadays)  or something else I usually say at the beginning that I'm sorry but I may have to step away for a few minutes.

Comment: @kgr: One other issue is that this only covers plannable breaks - this wouldn't solve the issue of cats shredding furniture, or a situation I've found myself in late last year - in a meeting while the apartment-building-wide fire alarm went off, and I had to mention to my team that I would be away from my computer for a bit, because of the fire alarm, as they could then here. I could be on our text chat app, but then it turned out it was an actual fire, and we would have been delayed on getting back in beyond a simple false alarm.

Comment: The fire alarm is obviously rare enough to not count as a recurring problem. If your cat shreds your furniture in ways that require your intercvention often enough to distract you from meetings on the regular, you have a separate cat-and-furniture problem to solve irrespective of meetings. Is chasing the cat away from furniture really time well spent to you? If not, design an environment for the cat where they can be they. Otherwise explain to your team that you enjoy chasing your cat very much, to the point where you've willingly set up a situation where you'll randomly drop out to do that.

Comment: @kqr: A fire alarm being not recurring is...dependent on the situation you're in. And a cat-furniture problem is usually easier to resolve in a way that doesn't have the cat continuously meow about being left out of furniture'd rooms (Which won't work for studio apartments), or having subpar furniture that you can let a cat scratch up. Regardless, etiquette for "On the spot" breaks is more useful than "Just solve the other problems so you don't need an impromptu break."

Comment: I would still argue that if you're trying to combine a life of constant (figurative) fire alarms and cat-furniture-shredding situations with a job that truly requires long, back-to-back meetings, you're in a situation where the personal and professional aspects of your life are incompatible. Something has to budge, and this is doing a great disservice to yourself and the ones that depend on you, either to be present in the meeting or to be available to handle all the other emergencies you're surrounded by. Needing a protocol to quietly slip out of meetings is just the warning signal.

Answer (score 6):

When I attend a meeting, physically or virtually, I self classify my role as a **Presenter**, an **Active Participant** or an **Audience**. From the role of my participation I implicate my rules of etiquette.

When I am a **presenter**, I am a focal person in the meeting. With regard to my own need for breaks in this role, it is my responsibility to structure my pre and post meeting time to meeting these needs. Typically an agenda for longer meetings should include plans for *everyone* to take a periodic break. As a presenter I may take an active role in orchestrating these breaks.

When I am an **active participant**, I am expecting to be actively listening and responding throughout the meeting. In this role, I make every attempt to be actively available throughout the meeting. If I am unable to[*](/#) than I will try to find an opportunity where the need for my presence is minimal and discretely announce that I will "be right back."

Finally as an **audience**, I am attending for my benefit. I will be actively listening, but not likely to be responding or questioned by the active participants for the duration of the meeting. I will still make find an opportunity where my presence feels least valuable before leaving. I will *not* interrupt the meeting to announce my departure, but leave and return quietly.

Virtually or physically, I feel it is never appropriate to carry on a meeting in a restroom or during other personal needs. Nobody wants to be the person who forgot to mute their device and flushed in front of the entire supreme count.

Comment: Yes; You should just treat it basically as a physical meeting.

Answer (score 3):

I like “I have to step away for a minute.”  That way “the bathroom” or “the dog” or whatever doesn’t need to be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll leave this up though much of it isn't applicable any more so I'll change the order/emphasis.  When I started answering yesterday the summary included the word "video" (checking the edit history - I didn't misremember).  By the time I posted on this morning's commute it had been updated.*

It's not clear whether this is audio-only using a computer-based client or a phone system; I effectively assume the former.

In general, I assume you don't want to interrupt the flow of the conference, by analogy with slipping out of a room, but want others to know you're temporarily gone and not just having connection issues.

Here are a few ideas that but be useful on their own or in addition to others:

- Most VOIP call clients allow you to set a status.  That alone may be sufficient, just toggling "away" as you get up and when you come back.  Some may act up if you change it while in a call, or refuse to do so, so you might want to test when it doesn't matter too much.
- Similarly some clients allow you to set a profile picture (to replace your video feed with a static image, for example) - change the image to report your status.  You could have a selection ready to use.
- It may be useful to have a headset that allows you to listen in without being able to speak.  I often use my bluetooth headphones (but a wired microphone) even while sat at my desk, because we have feedback issues in one regular meeting and it improves everyone's sound quality. I've been known to cook wile listening in to an overrunning meeting, for example.
- *If* you have sufficient influence/authority, calling for a break at a suitable time, such as between agenda items or presenters shouldn't make you unpopular - quite the opposite if done well. "How about we take 5.  I don't know about anyone else but I could do with getting some water"
- Actually "getting some water" above would probably be a euphemism for getting rid of some I'd already drunk. To actually have a drink.  keeping  a decent sized bottle at the desk is useful if you have lots of calls, to reduce interruptions.

---

And the video-based answers that aren't applicable any more:

- This one is brought to you by my 7-year old daughter, so depending on your workplace this may not count as "professional", but I have used it in informal meetings with colleagues, and it was well-received.  My desk chair is very high-backed, and she wrote "bye-bye" on a sheet of paper and pinned it to the back.  Spin the chair round to set your status assuming your video is on and the meeting client defaults to a suitable view.  You may wish to adjust the wording, perhaps "Away but listening, back in a moment".
- One thing I've seen to good effect (and done), was switching off the video feed when stepping away; that was in a case where the default was muted unless you needed to speak.  On some clients this is easily confused with a dropped call, so it doesn't always work.

Comment: If you're going to disagree, that's fine, but with several points, what are you disagreeing with?

Comment: I think the final bullet point is risky--if you mess that up you might wind up on one of those "Zoom horror stories" news articles. Not a risk I'd take...

Comment: I was talking about the water bottle. If it's for drinking, I'd definitely do it. If for not having to take bathroom breaks (which is how it read to me), then I would not.

Comment: @bob now that's clear I'll tidy my comments

Answer (score -6):

#### Technological Solution

Go portable. That can be:

- Wired or wireless headset with a portable (non-cellular) phone
- Wired or wireless headset with a cellular/smart phone
- Wireless headset with a computer.

A decent modern Bluetooth wireless headset will generally work up to 30 feet away. I often find myself walking around while using my wireless headset on my smart phone, to the degree that if I am really involved in the conversation and the phone isn't on my belt that I might even forget which room the phone is in! They're really that good.

Ideally, company should pay for headsets for everyone - the sound quality is far superior to a typical computer microphone, no speakers to annoy anyone else in the house, and much better than holding a phone up to your ear. They do *not* have to cost much. Yes, there are $200 headsets. But there are plenty of $20 - $30 headsets (both wired and wireless) that work just fine - and then you don't feel so bad if they break (dropped, stepped on, etc.).

The main thing is to be portable. That excludes a wired headset with a regular computer (even a laptop) because you're not going to carry a laptop into the bathroom (I hope). But with a wireless headset or a wired headset on a portable phone, you can hit mute and walk into the bathroom, or into the kitchen to get a beverage, or to the front door to receive a package, etc.

If your name comes while you are on mute and prefer to be unavailable, take 10 seconds to unmute and either give a quick answer or a "hang on, I have to take care of something, I'll be right back". That's much less intrusive than preemptively saying "I'll be back in 5 minutes" every time you step away from your desk. And in fact, you are not "away" if you are able to still listen in.

I would actually suggest being muted on an audio conference call most of the time, unless you are the main speaker or moderator, of course. That is normal etiquette on Zoom and really should be for audio conferences as well. That helps cut down on extraneous/unintentional interruptions (coughing, background noise, etc.) and *also* means that if you get up from your seat to do something else for a minute, you *don't* have to specifically mute yourself, because you are already muted.

I also highly recommend a "big headset" rather than AirPods or similar. I use something like (I've gone through a few at $20 - $30 each over the years) [this one from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3yLkF02):

[image: wireless headset]

Note the big boom microphone. If that's in front of your mouth and point to your headset (earpiece or microphone) when you answer the door, you will get the point across clearly and quickly that you are in the middle of a call. Yes, you *can* listen to music on one of these too, especially if it covers both ears (one reason I always get the single-ear headsets is so that I can legally and safely use them while driving), but the obvious microphone screams "I'm on a call!" in a way that AirPods don't.

Comment: Just because phones are portable does not mean you must treat them as always with you; you can "leave it at your virtual desk".

Comment: I have downvoted because bringing the conversation with you is not necessarily the brightest idea when you are interacting in person with someone at your door

Comment: unlike @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I find it quite helpful to take the meeting to the door - it gives a good excuse to get the caller dealt with quickly and on their way.  But the headset approach doesn't work well for that; a *handheld* phone/tablet/laptop makes it much clearer you're not just listening to music and being rude (so no vote either way from me).

Comment: This is especially not bright if you're going to the restroom.  No one, and I mean no one, is interested in sharing your experience in the case that you didn't push the mute button as you thought you did.